# Force Android emulator to show overflow button in Action Bar

Tags: android-layout, android-emulator

I'd like to test my interface with the overflow button. The overflow button only appears if there are too many items in the Action Bar *and* the device doesn't have a menu button. Is there any way to remove the menu button from the Android emulator, or otherwise force the overflow button to appear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the AVD manager, edit the particular AVD>Hardware ( A list of options Click add or edit) >Hardware Back /Home Keys =False

Comment: Updated: In the current AVD Manager, select "Device Definitions", then Edit or Clone a device definition.  In the edit dialog, set the "Buttons" option to "Software".